# Solving $u''(x)-\frac{u'(x)^2}{u(x)}+\frac{u'(x)}{x}=u(x)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to solve the following ODE:
$$u''(x)-\frac{u'(x)^2}{u(x)}+\frac{u'(x)}{x}=u(x)^2.$$
As far as I can see, none of the common methods to solve ODEs (separation of variables, integrating factor, Laplace transform, etc.) yield anything useful.

Can I have some guidance on how to solve this equation?

EDIT: I have, with the help of computer algebra systems, found the solution to this equation to be
$$u(x)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{AB}A^4x^{A-2}}{\left(x^A-\frac{A^2}2\mathrm{e}^{AB}\right)^2}$$
for arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$. However, I am still lost on how one might arrive at this solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$From the original equation $\dfrac{\d^2 u}{\d x^2} - \dfrac{1}{u} \left( \dfrac{\d u}{\d x} \right)^2 + \dfrac{1}{x} \dfrac{\d u}{\d x} = u^2$, letting $v = \dfrac{1}{ux^2}$ as @ClaudeLeibovici does yields$$
x^2 v \frac{\d^2 v}{\d x^2} - x^2 \left( \frac{\d v}{\d x} \right)^2 + xv \frac{\d v}{\d x} + v = 0,
$$
and letting $y = \ln x$ yields\begin{align*}
v \frac{\d^2 v}{\d y^2} - \left( \frac{\d v}{\d y} \right)^2 + v = 0.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Denoting $w = \dfrac{\d v}{\d y}$, (1) is equivalent to the following autonomous system:$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\d v}{\d y} = w\\
\dfrac{\d w}{\d y} = \dfrac{w^2}{v} - 1
\end{cases},
$$
and\begin{align*}
\frac{\d w}{\d v} = \frac{1}{w} \left( \dfrac{w^2}{v} - 1 \right) \Longrightarrow (v - w^2) \,\d v + vw \,\d w = 0.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The integrating factor of (2) is $\dfrac{1}{v^3}$, thus the solution to (2) is $\dfrac{w^2 - 2v}{2v^2} = C_1$, where $C_1$ is a constant. Now,$$
\frac{\d v}{\d y} = w = \pm\sqrt{\smash[b]{2C_1 v^2 + 2v}},
$$
which can be solved explicitly (with a lot of calculation).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a non-linear ODE such as this there is one last hope in finding a solution by plugging in a monomial $x^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, especially if the depedencies of "$x$" is only given by some monomials, such as in the third summand.

By trying this, you have to count the de-/increase of homogeneity in each term, i.e. $u''$ has homogeneity $\alpha-2$, $\frac{(u')^2}{u}$ has $2(\alpha-1)-\alpha$, $\frac{u}{x}$ has $(\alpha-1)-1$ and finally $u^2$ has homogeneity $2\alpha$. Since every term on the L.H.S. would provide the same homogeneity $\alpha-2$, we are looking for a monomial $x^\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha-2=2\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha=-2$.

We still need to find the right coefficient $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $u(x)=\beta x^ {-2}$ actually solves the equation. Again, applying yields $6\beta-4\beta^2-2\beta=\beta^2$ and since we exclude $\beta=0$ we get a solution with $\beta=\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Nice thought, but I am afraid there is a slight mistake. The second term in the equation for $\beta$ should be $4\beta$ instead of $4\beta^2$, leading to the equation $6\beta-4\beta-2\beta=\beta^2\iff \beta=0$, which only gives us the solution $u(x)=0$.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

After @dennis_s's answer, what I tried (after a few other attempts), is to let $y=\frac 1{z x^2}$ which leads to
$$x^2 z z''-x^2 z'^2+x z z'+z=0$$ which is solvable ... using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dsolve+x%5E2+z+z%27%27-x%5E2+z%27%5E2%2Bx+z+z%27%2Bz%3D0+for+z).

Rearranging the result, 
$$z=\frac{e^{\sqrt{c_1} c_2} x^{-\sqrt{c_1}}+e^{-\sqrt{c_1} c_2} x^{\sqrt{c_1}}-2 } {2c_1}$$

Comment: Hi! I have also played around with transforming the equation in this manner, but I am interested in how we actually arrive at such a solution. Do you have any ideas on how we actually solve the equation? I was able to solve my equation using CAS systems, but I am interested in how it can be done by hand.

Comment: @AlvinL-B. The formula you give is really nice. Which CAS did you use ? Concerning your question, .... I have the same ! I have been working hours this problem with no success (thanks to the containment). Cheers :-)

Comment: My first observation was that just plugging the [original equation into WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27%28x%29-u%27%28x%29%5E2%2Fu%28x%29%2Bu%27%28x%29%2Fx%3Du%28x%29%5E2) does not work, because it gives a completely wrong answer. Instead, I transformed the equation into another one (using $v(x)=\ln(u(x))$, which [WolframAlpha was able to solve correctly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=v%27%27%28x%29%2Bv%27%28x%29%2Fx%3De%5E%28v%28x%29%29), with two quite ugly solutions (which I could show were really the same solution). I then cleaned them up by hand.

Answer (score 0):

A series approximation. First, the original ODE is transformed with the change of variables $v = \frac{u'}{u}$ resulting in the equivalent system

$$
\cases{
x v'+v = x u\\
u'= u v
}
$$

now making

$$
u = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k\\
v = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k\\
$$

and substituting into the ODE system we obtain for $n=2m+1, m = 0,1, \cdots,N$ the approximations

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
n & u & v\\
1 & a_0 & \frac{x a_0}{2} \\
3 & \frac{1}{4} x^2 a_0^2+a_0 & \frac{1}{16} a_0^2 x^3+\frac{a_0 x}{2} \\
5 & \frac{3}{64} a_0^3 x^4+\frac{1}{4} a_0^2 x^2+a_0 & \frac{1}{128} a_0^3 x^5+\frac{1}{16} a_0^2 x^3+\frac{a_0 x}{2} \\
7 & \frac{1}{128} a_0^4 x^6+\frac{3}{64} a_0^3 x^4+\frac{1}{4} a_0^2 x^2+a_0 & \frac{a_0^4x^7}{1024}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^3 x^5+\frac{1}{16} a_0^2 x^3+\frac{a_0 x}{2} \\
9 & \frac{5 a_0^5 x^8}{4096}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^4 x^6+\frac{3}{64} a_0^3 x^4+\frac{1}{4} a_0^2 x^2+a_0 &
   \frac{a_0^5 x^9}{8192}+\frac{a_0^4 x^7}{1024}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^3 x^5+\frac{1}{16} a_0^2 x^3+\frac{a_0x}{2} \\
11 & \frac{3 a_0^6 x^{10}}{16384}+\frac{5 a_0^5 x^8}{4096}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^4 x^6+\frac{3}{64} a_0^3x^4+\frac{1}{4} a_0^2 x^2+a_0 & \frac{a_0^6 x^{11}}{65536}+\frac{a_0^5 x^9}{8192}+\frac{a_0^4 x^7}{1024}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^3 x^5+\frac{1}{16} a_0^2 x^3+\frac{a_0 x}{2} \\
13 & \frac{7 a_0^7 x^{12}}{262144}+\frac{3 a_0^6 x^{10}}{16384}+\frac{5 a_0^5 x^8}{4096}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^4x^6+\frac{3}{64} a_0^3 x^4+\frac{1}{4} a_0^2 x^2+a_0 & \frac{a_0^7 x^{13}}{524288}+\frac{a_0^6
   x^{11}}{65536}+\frac{a_0^5 x^9}{8192}+\frac{a_0^4 x^7}{1024}+\frac{1}{128} a_0^3 x^5+\frac{1}{16} a_0^2
   x^3+\frac{a_0 x}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

For $a_0 = 1$ we have the approximations

[image]

NOTE

The only problem we observe in this approach is that it depends only on one arbitrary constant and not on two as would be expected. The even curves are $u$ and the odd are $v$ approximations.

Comment: Hi! Nice result, but I was looking to get an exact closed-form expression for the solution to this equation (which is definitely possible, see my edit to the question). Is it perhaps possible to adapt these series of yours in order to get the closed-form expression in my original post?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks immensely to @Saad for giving an outline of the method of solution. Here is what I came up with when following their thoughts through to the end and filling in some of the details.

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$ We first apply the transformation $u=\frac{1}{vx^2}$ to the original equation
$$\frac{\d^2u}{\d x^2}-\frac{1}{u}\left(\frac{\d u}{\d x}\right)^2+\frac{1}{x}\frac{\d u}{\d x}-u^2=0.$$
The chain rule lets us differentiate $u=\frac{1}{vx^2}$ to get expressions for $\frac{\d^2u}{\d x^2}$ and $\frac{\d u}{\d x}$ in terms of $v$, eventually giving
$$x^2v\frac{\d^2v}{\d x}-x^2\left(\frac{\d v}{\d x}\right)^2+xv\frac{\d v}{\d x}+v=0.$$
@Saad's cleverness is now to introduce a new independent variable $t=\ln(x)\iff x=e^t$. The chain rule expresses the derivatives in terms of $t$ as
$$\frac{\d v}{\d x}=\frac{\d v}{\d t}\frac{\d t}{\d x}=\frac{\d v}{\d t}\frac{1}{x}\iff\frac{\d v}{\d x}=\frac{\d v}{\d t}\cdot e^{-t}$$ 
and
$$\frac{\d^2 v}{\d x^2}=\frac{\d}{\d x}\left(\frac{\d v}{\d t}\cdot e^{-t}\right)=\frac{\d t}{\d x}\frac{\d}{\d t}\left(\frac{\d v}{\d t}\cdot e^{-t}\right)=\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\d^2v}{\d t^2}-\frac{\d v}{\d t}\right).$$
Plugging this into the equation, we get
$$v\frac{\d^2 v}{\d t^2}-\left(\frac{\d v}{\d t}\right)^2+v=0.$$
We see that the substitution has given us an autonomous equation. We can solve it by letting $u=\frac{\d v}{\d t}$ and treating $v$ as the independent variable. We observe that
$$\frac{\d^2v}{\d t^2}=\frac{\d u}{\d t}=\frac{\d v}{\d t}\frac{\d u}{\d v}=u\frac{\d u}{\d v}.$$
In our equation, this yields
$$uv\frac{\d u}{\d v}-u^2+v=0.$$
We would like to solve this using the method of exact equations, but we note that the equation in this form is not exact, as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(v-u^2\right)=-2u\neq u=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(uv\right).$$
We can however multiply both sides by an integrating factor $\mu(v)$ to put the equation into exact form. We seek $\mu(v)$ such that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\mu(v)(v-u^2)\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\mu(v)uv\right) \\
\iff\quad&-2u\cdot\mu(v)=uv\cdot\mu'(v)+u\cdot\mu(v)\\
\iff\quad&-3u\cdot\mu(v)=uv\cdot\mu'(v)\\
\iff\quad&-3\mu(v)=v\cdot\mu'(v)\\
\iff\quad&\frac{\mu'(v)}{\mu(v)}=\frac{-3}{v}\\
\iff\quad&\int\frac{1}{\mu}\ \d\mu=\int\frac{-3}{v}\ \d v\\
\iff\quad&\ln(\mu(v))=\ln(v^{-3})\\
\iff\quad&\mu(v)=\frac{1}{v^3}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying both sides in the differential equation by this integrating factor then results in
$$\frac{1}{v^2}-\frac{u^2}{v^3}+\frac{u}{v^2}\frac{\d u}{\d v}=0.$$
Now that the equation is exact, we know that there must be a function $\Psi(u,v)$ such that
$$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{v^2}-\frac{u^2}{v^3}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial u}=\frac{u}{v^2}.$$
Integrating the first equation with respect to $v$ gives
$$\Psi=-\frac{1}{v}+\frac{u^2}{2v^2}+\varphi(u).$$
Differentiation with respect to $u$ and comparison with the other equation shows that $\varphi'(u)=0\iff\varphi(u)=k$ for some constant $k$ (which we can ignore, since it can be "baked into" $c_1$ later). It then follows from the multivariate chain rule that the solution to our equation is given by
\begin{align*}
&\Psi=c_1\\
\iff\quad&\frac{u^2}{2v^2}-\frac{1}{v}=c_1\\
\iff\quad&u^2=2v+2c_1v^2\\
\iff\quad&u=\pm\sqrt{2v+c_2v^2}.
\end{align*}
Since $u=\frac{\d v}{\d t}$, we are now tasked with solving
$$\frac{\d v}{\d t}=\pm\sqrt{2v+c_2v^2}.$$
We are in luck, as the equation is separable if we write it as follows
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2v+c_2v^2}}\frac{\d v}{\d t}=\pm1.$$
Integrating both sides then gives us
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2v+c_2v^2}}\ \d v=\int\pm1\ \d t.$$
The left hand side integral is somewhat tricky. We begin by factoring out $\sqrt{c_2}$ in the denominator, giving
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2v+c_2v^2}}\ \d v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c_2}v+v^2}}\ \d v.$$
Following this up by completing the square in the denominator, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c_2}v+v^2}}\ \d v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(v+\frac{1}{c_2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{c_2^2}}}\ \d v.$$
To straighten this, we use a hyperbolic substitution, making use of the identity $\cosh^2(x)-1=\sinh^2(x)$. We want a substitution such that
\begin{align*}
&\left(v+\frac{1}{c_2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{c_2^2}\cosh^2(\eta)\\
\iff\quad&v+\frac{1}{c_2}=\frac{1}{c_2}\cosh(\eta)\\
\iff\quad&v=\frac{1}{c_2}\cosh(\eta)-\frac{1}{c_2}\\
\iff\quad&\d v=\frac{1}{c_2}\sinh(\eta)\ \d\eta.
\end{align*}
Our integral is thus transformed into
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c_2}v+v^2}}\ \d v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{\frac{1}{c_2}\sinh(\eta)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_2^2}\cosh^2(\eta)-\frac{1}{c_2^2}}}\ \d\eta.$$
Using $\cosh^2(\eta)-1=\sinh^2(\eta)$, this vastly simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{\frac{1}{c_2}\sinh(\eta)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_2^2}\cosh^2(\eta)-\frac{1}{c_2^2}}}\ \d\eta&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int\frac{\sinh(\eta)}{\sqrt{\cosh^2(\eta)-1}}\ \d\eta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1}}\int\frac{\sinh(\eta)}{\sqrt{\sinh^2(\eta)}}\ \d\eta\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\int 1\ \d\eta=\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{c_2}}
\end{align*}
(I'm ignoring the integration constant since we can include it in $c_3$ later). We can solve for $\eta$ in the equation where we defined the substitution to get $\eta=\cosh^{-1}(c_2v+1)$. This gives that the integral is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\cosh^{-1}(c_2v+1)$, which gives our differential equation as
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\cosh^{-1}(c_2v+1)=\pm t+c_3\\
\iff\quad&c_2v+1=\cosh(\pm\sqrt{c_2}t+\sqrt{c_2}c_3)\\
\iff\quad&c_5^2v+1=\cosh(c_5t+c_4),
\end{align*}
where in the last step we let $c_4=\sqrt{c_2}c_3$ and $c_5=\pm\sqrt{c_2}$ ($c_5^2$ is the same regardless of the sign of $c_5$). We now get $v$ as
$$v=\frac{1}{c_5^2}\left(\cosh(c_5t+c_4)-1\right).$$
Using the definition of the hyperbolic cosine function and $t=\ln(x)$, we get
\begin{align*}
v&=\frac{1}{c_5^2}\left(\frac{e^{c_5t+c_4}+e^{-c_5t-c_4}}{2}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2c_5^2}\left(e^{c_5t+c_4}+\frac{1}{e^{c_5t+c_4}}-2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2c_5^2}\left(e^{c_5t}\cdot c_6-2+\frac{1}{e^{c_5t}\cdot c_6}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2c_5^2c_6}\left(c_6^2x^{c_5}-2c_6+\frac{1}{x^{c_5}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2c_5^2c_6x^{c_5}}\left(c_6^2x^{2c_5}-2c_6x^{c_5}+1\right)\\
&=\frac{(c_6x^{c_5}-1)^2}{2c_5^2c_6x^{c_5}}.
\end{align*}
Now we can at last solve for $u$ using $u=\frac{1}{vx^2}$:
$$u=\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{(c_6x^{c_5}-1)^2}{2c_5^2c_6x^{c_5}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{2c_5^2c_6x^{c_5-2}}{(c_6x^{c_5}-1)^2}.$$
Cleaning up by letting $A=c_5$ and $B=c_6$, we finally get
$$u(x)=\frac{2A^2Bx^{A-2}}{(Bx^A-1)^2}.$$
Compared to the solution given in the original post
$$u(x)=\frac{e^{AB_1}A^4x^{A-2}}{\left(x^A-\frac{A^2}{2}e^{AB_1}\right)^2}$$
(In the original post, $B$ is a different constant to $B$ here, hence I use $B_1$ to distinguish them),

the solution we have stumbled upon is actually even nicer. Also notice the equivalence of the two solutions by letting $B=\dfrac{2}{A^2e^{AB_1}}$.